# MissingMethodInvocationException when calling public non static function on a mock object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

Im writing a test using Mockito. My class looks like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MailContainsAttachmentJsonFilterTest {

    private MailContainsAttachmentJsonFilter mailContainsAttachmentJsonFilter;
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            mailContainsAttachmentJsonFilter = new MailContainsAttachmentJsonFilter();
        javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    }
```

And the test:

```
@Test
public void filterTest01() throws MessagingException, IOException {
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = Mockito.mock(MimeMessage.class);
    Folder folder = Mockito.mock(Folder.class);

    Mockito.when(folder.isOpen()).thenReturn(true);
    Mockito.when(mimeMessage.getFolder()).thenReturn(folder);

    MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);

    messageHelper.addAttachment("test.json", new ByteArrayDataSource("{}", "application/json"));
    Mockito.when(mimeMessage).thenReturn(messageHelper.getMimeMessage());

    mailContainsAttachmentJsonFilter.filter(mimeMessage);
}
```

When I run the test, as soon as I reach the `Mockito.when(folderisOpen()).thenReturn(true)`, I get:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not 
supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other 
object.
```

`MimeMessage` and `Folder` are both from `javax.mail`.

As far as I can tell, none of the methods I try to mock, are final/private/equals()/hashcode().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed method call in this line:

```
Mockito.when(mimeMessage).thenReturn(messageHelper.getMimeMessage());
```

So you should change "mimeMessage" to "mimeMessage.someMethodCall()"

Comment: That did it. I didn't know the exception was thrown at compile time, and since I never reached any of the lines after `Mockito.when(folderisOpen()).thenReturn(true)`, I was convinced the error was on that line.